# Y-axis of a graph with a common unit but different meanings

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I have a graph where the x-axis is time and y-axis is the density of two or more different organisms. So the graph shows how the densities change with time. Suppose the species are tunas and whales, and the plot shows the data for the both species together. Should the label for the y-axis `Density` or `Densities`? I have seen both ways...

Answer (score 1):

Density. The axis is only a measurement scale. At any given time, each data set has only one value.

Answer (score 1):

You should label it *density* unless you're doing something really peculiar.

At any given point of time, an animal (or group of animals, if this is an aggregation or population density) possesses a single density. They probably possess multiple *units* of density measurement - e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28density%29) lists the average density of a human as 1062 kg/m<sup>3</sup> - but only a single density<sup>*</sup>.

Your Y axis counts *units* of density measurement, not *numbers* of densities; it quantifies the quality rather than asking how many different instances of that quality exist. Unless you're using *density* as the metric for determine number of populations of animals (e.g. a density of 10 animals/km<sup>2</sup> and another location having a density of 15 animals/km<sup>2</sup> demarcates them as different populations). But that's a really crazy way to count population groups.

<sup>*</sup> - Yes, I realize the density will be different at different places in the body, but at that level we're talking about *tissue* densities, not *human* density. Even a heterogeneous body has only a single density when considered as a whole. I also realize this is most likely about population density, but it's a lot cooler to me to think of it in terms of physical body density, and that doesn't change the answer, or even the above asterisk (with appropriate terminological substitutions of course).